# how to make work a web service compiled with java 1.3 in a java 1.6 project?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, java-6

i'm working on a java EE application made with flash builder 3, hibernate, Apache CXF and spring. the jre i'm using is 1.6. but i've a service that has to be compiled with java 1.3. my application server is tomcat 6.

here's my problem, how can i work with 1.6 and 1.3 at the same time? is the fact of mentionning that the classes should be compiled with a 1.3 compatibility enough?

otherwise, should i use 2 different tomcat version (one where i'll deploy the 1.6 services & the other with that particular service) could they communicate??? and do i need to use axis on the 1.3 side??

i'm pretty lost, and any help for what architecture im supposed to use will be very welcome.

thanx

Comment: whats the problem if you complie with 1.6 and use the same for 1.3 compatibilty? As 1.6 is higher version, so it will contain depricated class of 1.3 too

Comment: well the service can only be compiled with 1.3 (it's a requirement according to the service provider doc).

Comment: then you can move to complie with differnt versions and running the applications in cluster server

Comment: then compile the service with 1.3, put it in a `.jar` and use that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to develop with Java 1.6 and deploy to a Java 1.3 web container. That's going to be fairly difficult to do. You could use [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/) to make your classes you compiled with 1.6 compatible with 1.3. You can even use enums, generics and a few other things.

You will however be very restricted on what system and third party libraries you can use. You can't use any system classes and methods that aren't in 1.3 (note that 1.4 and 1.5 introduced a lot of useful classes). The same will apply to any libraries you depend on. And if they're compiled with a version later than 1.3 you'll have to use Retroweaver on those too. Not to mention you need a version of Tomcat that runs on 1.3.

It'll likely be painful to setup and maintain this, if it's even feasible. And if you're deploying them with services that can run on 1.6, it'd be severely restricting those as well. You'll probably be better off with two projects, one for 1.3 and one for 1.6. Then however it's up to you to have the services communicate, e.g. with REST or RMI.

Comment: thanks for ure reply, ok can u explain to me the solution of working with 2 different projects?